# How to handle lightbox using java in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am beginner with selenium webdriver. Need help as how to handle the lightbox during webdriver. i tried alert and pop-ups. For eg. 1. navigate to www.amazon.com 2. A lightbox is displayed asking if you wish to be navigated to www.amazon.in or stay here. Please help to click on the amazon.in but

Comment: did you tried direct click with Thread.sleep(5000) in java? or with waits?

Answer (score 0):

Seems straight-forward selenium command:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='redir-go-to-site']/span[2]")).click();
```

Find the element you want to click on from firepath addon on firebug addon and use the xpath. Or you can build your own xpath.

Comment: Hey thanks Parishodak, but this isn't working. I am not able to click on the amazon.com/amazon.in buttons. I tried also switchTo alert. Not working either. Not sure if its a frame..

Comment: @Patrick, post the code you are trying. you will get better responses faster

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-lightbox");
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Open a Div in Lightbox')]"));
element.click();
WebElement frameElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/wswxQ3mhwqQ']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label=\'Play\']")).click();
```

Comment: Could you add explanation what this code does and how it answers original question

Comment: It will open light box and will switch control to the lightbox, perform desired action in light box